# How to make a filter with query string in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to make a filter with query params, here I want to make 3 where, but if one of them is not there, then it will not be a problem because it will display according to the filter only, and if there is no query string then it will display all data

```
public function VendorInfoFilter(Request $request)
    {
        $vendor  = DB::table('schema.data as d')
                    ->where('d.status','=',$request->status)
                    ->orderBy('d.id')
                    ->get();   
        return response()->json($vendor);

    }
```

Comment: https://laraveldaily.com/less-know-way-conditional-queries/

Comment: thankyou sir, it'works but now i have error for filter second
SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input value for enum

Comment: Post your code in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take as reference, exact code might not work for you.

```
public function VendorInfoFilter(Request $request)
{
    $vendor  = DB::table('schema.data as d');

    if (!empty($request->status_one)) {
        $vendor = $vendor->where('d.status','=', $request->status_one);    
    }

    if (!empty($request->status_two)) {
        $vendor = $vendor->where('d.status','=', $request->status_two);  
    }

    if (!empty($request->status_three)) {
        $vendor = $vendor->where('d.status','=', $request->status_three); 
    }

    if (empty($request->status_one) && empty($request->status_two) && empty($request->status_three)) {
        $vendor= $vendor->where('d.status','=', $request->status_one)->where('d.status','=', $request->status_two)->where('d.status','=', $request->status_three);
    }

    $result = $vendor->orderBy('d.id')
                ->get();   

    return response()->json($result);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public function VendorInfoFilter(Request $request)
    {
        $vendor  = DB::table('schema.data as d')
                    ->when($request->status, function ($q, $status) { 
                       return $q->where('d.status','=', $status);
                    })
                    ->when($request->status_two, function ($q, $status_two) { 
                       return $q->where('d.status_two','=', $status_two);
                    })
                    ->orderBy('d.id')
                    ->get();   
        return response()->json($vendor);

    }
```

Comment: thank you sir, but now i found error like this
SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input value for enum

Comment: Your query contains enum that doesn't accept/declare on the table enum field. Show me your table structure.